# JPA entity with composite primary and foreign keys

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have an entity with a composite primary key consisting of two fields, one of which is also part of a composite foreign key.

Background: I have entities `Person`,`Area`, and `Session`.

`Person` has many-to-many relationships with `Area` and `Session`, using join entities called `PersonArea` and `PersonSession`.

So, I have `PersonSession`, with primary key of (`personId`, `sessionId`). 
`PersonId` and `SessionId` are themselves foreign keys to `Person` and `Session`.

`PersonSession` also has a field `areaId`.
I want (`personId`, `areaId`) to be a composite foreign key to `PersonArea`.

My code for PersonSession:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="person_session")
@IdClass(PersonSession.ID.class)
public class PersonSession {

  @Id
  private int personId ;

  @Id
  private int sessionId;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "personId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Person person;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "sessionId", updatable = false, insertable = false, referencedColumnName = "id")
  private Session session;

  @ManyToOne//(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "personId", updatable = false, insertable = false),
    @JoinColumn(name = "areaId", updatable = false, insertable = false),
  })
  private PersonArea personArea;
```

}

Code for `PersonSession.Id`

```
public static class ID implements Serializable {
    private int personId;
    private int sessionId;
}
```

This seems OK, it creates all the correct relationships in the database. The problem comes when I try to insert PersonSession objects - the areaId column is always null, I think that is because it's defined a `updatable=false, insertable=false`.

However, if I try and make it updatable and insertable, I get an exception complaining the personId is a repeated column:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: foo.bar.PersonSession column: personId (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

How can I have the required relationships AND have areaId updatable and insertable?

Comment: A quick observation can't you make areaId updateable & insertable and leave personId as is? Or may be that is what you are doing but getting a exception on personId...?

Comment: No, I tried that, I get `... org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Mixing insertable and non insertable columns in a property is not allowed`

Comment: Person - Area is N:N using PersonArea, Person Session is N:N using PersonSession. Person-Session has Person-Area. Could you show how this is modelled in the DB. Why is one many-to-many link linked to another. It might be helpful to paste the other entities as well.

Answer (score 1):

I *should* be able to do what I want with this:

```
@ManyToOne//(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumns({
  @JoinColumn(name = "personId"),
  @JoinColumn(name = "areaId", updatable = false, insertable = false),
})
private PersonArea personArea;
```

But Hibernate does not support mixing updatable and non updatable Join Columns. The accepted answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231452/should-hibernate-be-able-to-handle-overlapping-foreign-keys) indicates that it might be supported at some time, but it seems the developers aren't very worried about that shortcoming.

I have how ditched Hibernate in favour of [Eclipselink](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/) and it works!

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late but I faced the same problem and I used @JoinColumnsOrFormulas to resolve it. Here is what you could do:

```
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name="personId", referencedColumnName = "personId")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value="areaId", referencedColumnName = "areaId"))}) 
private PersonArea personArea;
```