# How to implement a Composite Primary Key in Spring Data and Hibernate that can be used for JOINs?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, orm, spring-data

I am working on Spring Boot project with JPA and Hibernate, and implementing a multi-tenanted entity relationship with many related tables. All the tables will have tenantId as one of the columns.

I am implementing a Composite Primary Key for all the tables as suggested [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-16179?focusedCommentId=111115). (Also tried using Hibernate Filters and `@TenantId`, but these do not work for Joins).

I have defined the entities like this -

**BaseTenantId - Composite Primary Key Class**

```
    @Data
    public class BaseTenantId implements Serializable {

        private UUID id;
        private Long tenantId;
    }
```

**EntityA**

```
    @IdClass(BaseTenantId.class)
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table("table_a")
    public class EntityA {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private UUID id;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tenant_id")
        private Long tenantId;

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityA", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<EntityB> entityBList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

**EntityB**

```
    @IdClass(BaseTenantId.class)
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table("table_b")
    public class EntityB {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private UUID id;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tenant_id")
        private Long tenantId;


        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumns(
            value = {
                @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "entity_a_id"),
                @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "tenant_id", name = "tenant_id")
            })
        private EntityA entityA;   

        @OneToMany(mappedBy = "entityC", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        private List<EntityC> entityCList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
```

**EntityC**

```
    @IdClass(BaseTenantId.class)
    @Entity
    @Data
    @Table("table_c")
    public class EntityC {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue
        private UUID id;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "tenant_id")
        private Long tenantId;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumns(
            value = {
                @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "id", name = "entity_b_id"),
                @JoinColumn(referencedColumnName = "tenant_id", name = "tenant_id")
            })
        private EntityC entityC; 
    }
```

The requirement is whenever Hibernate executes any Join query or a Direct Fetch query, both `id` and `tenant_id` should be added as clauses to the SQL query (Implementing for a tenantId based Partitioned Postgres Database).

So, I added both the columns within `@JoinColumns` on the `@ManyToOne` side.

Now the problem is, When I try to persist an entity using `entityA_Repository.save(entityA)` to the database, this fails with the following exception (omitting certain logs for brevity) -

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement [No value specified for parameter 3.]

    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:108)
```

SQL generated by Hibernate -

```
insert 
    into
        table_a
        (tenant_id, entity_a_id, tenant_id, id) 
    values
        (?,?,?,?)
```

On enabling TRACE logs for the values binding, figured out that `tenant_id` column is added twice in the insert statement, and the value is not set for the repeated `tenant_id` column, and hence the above mentioned exception is thrown.

I am assuming that the Bi-Directional mapping between entities is causing the problem, and I am looking for a way out here. I tried using the `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas` annotation instead of `@JoinColumns` annotation as specified in this SO answer - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802879/15845659, but it throws another exception as follows, and the Spring Boot app does not even start -

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name ‘entityManagerFactory’ defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: value involves formulas

Caused by: org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: value involves formulas
at org.hibernate.mapping.SimpleValue.getColumns(SimpleValue.java:282)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.TableBinder.mappedByColumns(TableBinder.java:773)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.TableBinder.bindUnownedAssociation(TableBinder.java:755)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.TableBinder.bindForeignKey(TableBinder.java:546)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.internal.CollectionBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:2587)
```

What is the right way to implement this mapping assuming there are many more related tables? Thanks in advance.