# Can Hibernate handle overlapping columns in composite types?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, compositeusertype

There is a known hibernate bug https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-6221 where overlapping foreign keys triggers an AnnotationException. In `@JoinColumns`, you cannot have a mix of insertable and non-insertable `@JoinColumn` entries.

This has a workaround using `@JoinColumnsOrFormulas`, https://stackoverflow.com/a/13147366/16400385 .

The same bug is there for `@Columns`, but I can't find a `@ColumnsOrFormulas` annotation. Is there a similar workaround for `@Columns` ?

sample code

```
    @Columns( columns = {
        @Column(name = "currency_id", updatable = false, insertable = false),
        @Column(name = "fees")
    })
    private Money fees;

    @Columns( columns = {
            @Column(name = "currency_id"),
            @Column(name = "tax")
    })
    private Money tax;
```

the error I get is

> 'org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Mixing insertable and non
> insertable columns in a property is not allowed'

, same as HHH-6221

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no workaround or anything for this as that kind of model simply is problematic/broken. One thing you could do is to map the individual columns in your entity and build a money instance through a `@PostLoad` listener.

Comment: Thanks! is that the right way to create a Money Value object with Hibernate? https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/money.html . While my annotations could certainly be problematic or broken, the concept of a Money Value Object is not.

Comment: Sure, the concept is totally fine, but the mapping simply isn't how about you keep the mapping the way you have it, with the only adjustment being, that you have a dedicated column for the currency per attribute. This would work for Hibernate as well.