# HIbernate not inserting due to not-nullconstraint with composite FK

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm trying to save a complex entity with Hibernate where we have multiple entities with composite keys.
When I try tosave it seems that Hibernate it is not retrieving correctly the values from some columns on child entities which have composite key hence postgre is returning a not-null violation error.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activities", schema = "ptw")
@Data
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "jsonb", typeClass = JsonBinaryType.class),
        @TypeDef(name = "pg-id-uuid", typeClass = PostgresIdUUIDType.class)
})
public class Activity extends AuditAtBy implements Serializable {

@EmbeddedId
private CommonId commonId;

@MapsId("siteId")
@ManyToOne
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
@Type(type = "pg-id-uuid")
@JoinColumn(name="site_id",referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid", updatable = false)
private Site site;

@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value="location_id", referencedColumnName = "id")),
        @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value="site_id", referencedColumnName = "site_id"))})
@Type(type = "pg-id-uuid")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private Location location;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "job_pack_id", referencedColumnName = "id", columnDefinition = "uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn( name = "site_id", referencedColumnName="site_id", columnDefinition = "uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
@Type(type = "pg-id-uuid")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private JobPack jobPack;

@Column(name = "permit_number", nullable = false, length = 10)
private String permitNumber;

@Column(name = "order_number", nullable = false)
private short orderNumber;


@Column(name = "location_name", length = 200)
private String locationName;

**@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "state_id", referencedColumnName="id", columnDefinition = "uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "site_id", referencedColumnName="site_id", columnDefinition = "uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
@Type(type = "pg-id-uuid")
private ActivityState state;**

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
        @JoinColumn(name = "activity_type_id", referencedColumnName="id", columnDefinition = "uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false),
        @JoinColumn(name = "site_id", referencedColumnName="site_id", columnDefinition = "uuid", insertable = false, updatable = false)
})
@Type(type = "pg-id-uuid")
@OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
private ActivityType activityType;




public UUID getId(){
    return this.getCommonId().getId();
}

public void setId(UUID id){
    if (this.getCommonId() == null) {
        this.setCommonId(new CommonId());
    }
    this.getCommonId().setId(id);
}

public void setSite(Site site){
    this.site = site;
    if (this.getCommonId() == null) {
        this.setCommonId(new CommonId());
    }
    this.getCommonId().setSiteId(site.getId());
}
}
```

The setId/getId/ setSite are overriden in order to update the entity when using a mapper to convert from the DTO to the Entity

The ActivityState is as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "activity_states", schema = "ptw")
@Data
@TypeDefs({
        @TypeDef(name = "pg-id-uuid", typeClass = PostgresIdUUIDType.class)
})
public class ActivityState extends AuditAtBy implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CommonId commonId;

    @MapsId("siteId")
    @ManyToOne
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    private Site site;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 50)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "icon_id", nullable = false)
    private short iconId;

    @Column(name = "is_initial", nullable = false)
    private boolean isInitial;

    @Column(name = "order_number", nullable = false)
    private short orderNumber;

    public UUID getId(){
        return this.getCommonId().getId();
    }

    public void setId(UUID id){
        if (this.getCommonId() == null) {
            this.setCommonId(new CommonId());
        }
        this.getCommonId().setId(id);
    }

    public void setSite(Site site){
        this.site = site;
        if (this.getCommonId() == null) {
            this.setCommonId(new CommonId());
        }
        this.getCommonId().setSiteId(site.getId());
    }
}
```

When I try to save the exception is:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "state_id" violates not-null constraint
  Detail: Failing row contains (c821ff72-de93-4c03-abf5-e18347c29955, null, 0, 5081790f-19ed-44e0-be17-94f94aed878b, null, null, test, test, null, 1, 1, f, N/A, 1, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, f, {"title": "test", "DateTable": {"timeTo": "", "timeFrom": "", "v..., 2021-12-09 13:46:02.829157+01, 2021-12-09 13:46:02.829157+01, 7b0702c7-9f11-4a92-bfdf-7f98eb8ac94d, 7b0702c7-9f11-4a92-bfdf-7f98eb8ac94d, null, null, f).
```

I have no idea about how to solve although I have tried multiple things changing the mappings and relationships.
I know that composites keys are not the best approach but we have a multitenancy system where the best approach to keep data isolated was this one.

Comment: What do you expect from `insertable = false, updatable = false`? You have forced HBN to not populate values of state_id in DB, and HBD is not doing that.

Comment: Without that, I can not map the entity. When I try removing that value I et this: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.basf.swift.ptw.model.entity.Activity column: site_id (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")

Because I need to map more than one entity to same column site_id.

Comment: Fixed with this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231452/should-hibernate-be-able-to-handle-overlapping-foreign-keys
Using @JoinColumnsOrFormulas allowed us to remove the insertable= false and hance it is working.

Comment: Why not just mark that one state_id join column as insertable=true? You can leave the other site_id join column as insertable/updatable=false to avoid it being changed and affecting the entity's identity.

Comment: Actually you can not do that. HIbernate will fail when starting the app, all of the columns in a JoinColumns annotation need to have the same flags, so either both or them are insertable or not.
In order to avoid that problem we found that this approach would work.

    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = {
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name="state_id", referencedColumnName = "id")),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value="site_id", referencedColumnName = "site_id"))
    })

Answer (score 0):

The answer was basically the first answer to this post: [Should Hibernate be able to handle overlapping foreign keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231452/should-hibernate-be-able-to-handle-overlapping-foreign-keys)

Basically changing the mapping to be with the actual column as column and the one repeated in other entities as formula it is working now:

```
@JoinColumnsOrFormulas(value = { 
@JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name="state_id", referencedColumnName = "id")), 
@JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(value="site_id", referencedColumnName = "site_id")) })
```