# Bidirectional One to Many relation with composite primary and foreign key

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

In order to support high load rates, our team decided to apply table partitioning in Postgres. For this we needed a composite primary key. Respectively, other tables referencing partitioned tables will do this by specifying a composite foreign key.

**Here is the database ddl statement for creation of the a table:**

```
create table if not exists a
(
    id                             bigint     not null,
    date                   timestamp  not null,
    constraint "PK_a"
        primary key (id, date)
)
    partition by RANGE (date);

create table if not exists a_2023
   partition of a
        (
            primary key (id, date),
            )
        FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-01-01 00:00:00');
```

The ddl statement for table b:

```
create table if not exists b
(
    id                    bigint    not null,
    date          timestamp not null,
    a_fk            bigint,
    constraint pk_table_id
        primary key (id, date),
    constraint fk_a_b
        foreign key (a_fk, date) references a,
    foreign key (a_fk, date) references a_2023
)
    partition by RANGE (date);

create table if not exists b_2023
    partition of b
        (
            primary key (id, date),
            constraint fk_a_b
                foreign key (a_fk, date) references a
            )
        FOR VALUES FROM ('2023-01-01 00:00:00') TO ('2024-01-01 00:00:00');
```

**Example of the code in Spring Boot.**

The primary key class:

```
@Embeddable
class PK {
    private Long id;

    private LocalDateTime date;

    public PK(LocalDateTime date) {
        this.date= date;
    }

    public PK(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || Hibernate.getClass(this) != Hibernate.getClass(o)) return false;
        PK entity = (PK) o;
        return Objects.equals(this.date, entity.date) &&
                Objects.equals(this.id, entity.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return Objects.hash(date, id);
    }
// consturctor, getters and setters
}
```

The parent class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "a")
class A {
    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private PK id;

   @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "aFk")
   List<B> bs = new ArrayList<>();
// consturctor, getters and setters
}
```

The child class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
class B {
    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private PK id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("date")
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "a_fk", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "date", referencedColumnName = "date")
    })
    private aFk;
// consturctor, getters and setters
}
```

When I save the entities:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
A a = new A(new PK(id, now)); // id is a taken from the database by calling nextval

A savedA = entityManager.merge(a);

B b = new B(new PK(id, now), savedA); // id is a taken from the database by calling nextval
entityManager.merge(b);
```

Please note that date is both a primary and a foreign key for B.

The problem is that the a_fk field is null. When looking in the Hibernate insertion, the statement doesn't contain a_fk field. It seems like Hibernate is ignoring the JoinColumn contianing the a_Fk column. Tried with **CascadeType.ALL** in A class (in that case I was adding the list containing object B in the bs of A), the result is the same.
Also, if I delete `@MapsId("date")`, an error appears saying that I should set date JoinColumn as insertable and updatable to true. Tried to set insertable and updatable to true, another error saying: Column mappings for property 'null' mix insertable with 'insertable=false'.
If I set `@MapsId` without date, then Hibernate inserts a_fk and date, but the id of B is null.

Maybe someone had a similar situation and has some ideas how to handle it.

After a long research and trying different solutions, my team came to the following. Here is the changed class B:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "b")
class B {
    @Id
    @EmbeddedId
    private PK id;
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @MapsId("date")
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "a_fk", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            @JoinColumn(name = "date", referencedColumnName = "date")
    })
    private a;

    @Column(name = "a_fk")
    private Long aFk;

   public void setA(A a) {
        this.a= a;
        this.aFk = a.getPk().getId();
    }
// consturctor, getters and setters
}
```

However I'd like to know your opinion, is this solution ok?

Comment: MapsId won't work on partial keys like this - you'll have to remove that mapsId annotation and mark the either the join column "date" reference or the PK "date" as updatable=false, insertable=false so that there is only one writeable mapping for the column.

Comment: Tried to remove MapsId and to set date as updatable=false, insertable=false. I receive exception: Column mappings for property 'null' mix insertable with 'insertable=false'.

Comment: Show what you mean as I don't see how it wouldn't work, and the full error as I don't know what that you've posted might mean. If you remove the MapsId annotation, you should now have two mappings that set the "date" value in the B table. You'll manually need to set the date from the A reference, and mark the joinColumn for the 'date' as updatable=false, insertable=false, letting JPA know you are setting it yourself via the B.id.date property. Make sure it isn't null - and it could be just a hibernate bug or lack of support for JPA: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9567902/496099